# Traverse array for dynamic data,used for google visualization api in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-visualization

I am using the Google Visualization API to display a chart on a JSP page.Using session variables,I am able to get the dataset for the methods contained in the Google Visualization API.I am also able to load the data,but it retrieves only the first element of the array.How do I put all the values of the array?Here are the codes:

In AnalyzeUserClient.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var sessionId = <%= (ArrayList<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("arrayList") %>;

for(var i=0;i<sessionId.length;i++){
if(i%2==0){
    var category = sessionId[i];
}
else{
    var value = sessionId[i];
}
}

function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Category', 'Value'],
      [category,value],
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {title:"Percentage of Category for User:"});
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```
//HTML Code:
<div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly create a JavaScript array from a JSP variable, as you have tried to do in your code. You have to populate each element separately (or declare it as an exploded list).

Your JavaScript code is taking an array but you are then creating two (scalar/normal) vars (category, value) which you are adding to the `data` var - these are not a list/array so you will get the last 2 elements from your array only.

I'm assuming your original ArrayList contains values which are "pairs", so I would try something like this (not checked, so might have bugs):

```
<c:set var="arrayList"><%= (ArrayList<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("arrayList") %></c:set>
var sessionId = ["${fn:join(arrayList, '","')}"]; // will create a JS list
var categories = [], values = [], tuples = [];

for(var i=0;i<sessionId.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        categories.push(sessionId[i]);
    }
    else{
        values.push(sessionId[i]);
    }
}

// following loop assumes categories and values are the same length
for (var i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
    tuples.push([ categories[i], values[i] ]); // create a list of lists (tuples)
}

function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Category', 'Value'],
      tuples,
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {title:"Percentage of Category for User:"});
}
```

Edit, it might be easier to understand the second line if coded as:

```
var sessionId = [];
<c:forEach items="${arrayList}" var="id">
    sessionId.push("${id}"); // add them one at a time, assuming string values
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: As I said I wasn't able to test that code but it should be enough to get you started. Use the browser "view source" as we'll as firebug (or equivalent) to see where the JS is failing.

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not constructive. What are you seeing (errors, etc)?